# Auto Upload Service

Tags: android, upload, contentobserver, foreground-service

I am developing an Android Application that is supposed to auto-upload images as soon as they appear in the Media Store. For this, I have implemented a Content Observer which is registered inside a Foreground Service to constantly monitor the change in Media Store and there is an upload Service which is triggered onChange() of Content Observer.
I am considering not using the Foreground Service as it wastes a lot of resources, what would be the best way to implement this?

P.S. - I have considered using scheduled Service too, but that wouldn't be of that help.

Thank You.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html: "A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface." - so you need a service, for sure, but there's no such term as 'foreground service'

Comment: I do not see problems to use ContentObserver in a Service

Comment: I am not talking about the conventional Service, its a Foreground Service.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground ?